# How to Convert Date from React-DatePicker into String

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to convert Date into String format. First I want to get Date from react-datePicker and only want to convert it into single String UTC to String format "22-10-2020"

Comment: Please consider posting what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to convert the Date into string format then use `toLocaleDateString()` with the date i.e `new Date().toLocaleDateString(); // 26-11-2020. <- string`

Answer (score 3):

On your onChange event, you can get e.target.value and use like it `new Date(e.target.value).toISOString().split('T')`

Comment: This is working But it is not showing current date. It is show Date before the current date i.e. if current date is 26-12-2020 then it is showing 25-12-2020

Comment: Suggest not converting to an ISO String as dependent on the current time zone this will cause the wrong date to be displayed e.g Sat Jun 25 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)  - when converted to ISO will be 2022-06-24T23:00:00.000Z - which why the invalid date, whereas toLocaleDateString mentioned below will return 24/06/2022

Answer (score 1):

You can Do This Things with use of [Moment](https://momentjs.com/)
, You can Easyly switch you format and also play with date and time type. Moment js is Easy Way to play with such thing .